# How do I reverse this string properly in c#?

Tags: c#, string, replace

**Problem:**
I have many strings/equations in this format or one similar:
-4x^2 + 6x^5 -12y + 3xy

BUT I need them in the following order (the reverse - descending instead of ascending powers):
3xy - 12y + 6x^5 - 4x^2

**Current attempt (gets close):**

```
string str ="-4x^2 + 6x^5 -12y + 3xy";

var reverseString = string.Join(" ", str.Split(' ').Reverse());
//This returns: 3xy + 12y - 6x^5 + -4x^2
//Desired rtrn: 3xy - 12y + 6x^5 - 4x^2
```

**Issues with current attempt:**

- "+" and "-" are not reordered correctly.
- In the case of negative numbers "+ -" should just be " - ". (e.g 2x + -3x should be 2x - 3x).
- In the circumstance the equation starts with a negative number or
  is inside a bracket opening, this needs to still remain as "-2x" or
  "(-2x ...) (no space) for example not become "- 2x" with a space.

**Question:**

- How would I get the string and +/- in the correct order and fix the issues with my current attempt?
- Should I try again after learning regex? (If that's more suitable).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: There seems to be a missing operator in `6x^5 -12y`; is that supposed to be `6x^5 + -12y` or `6x^5 - 12y`?  You're splitting on spaces and there's no space between `-` and `12y`.

Comment: @BACON all three of your expressions are equivalent. Perhaps `6x^5 -12y` is there to show the parser should be able to parse that form.

Comment: @djv I understand they're equivalent, but where does the operator come from if there's none in the original text?  It says it returns `3xy + 12y - 6x^5 + -4x^2` when it actually returns `3xy + -12y 6x^5 + -4x^2`, so I'm trying to establish if this is a typo/miscopy or there's more code than what's shown here.  Either way makes for a more difficult to answer question.

Comment: @BACON and djv thank you for the help, they are as djv says equivalent. -12y is the output of parsing and + - 12y comes once the equation has been reordered with the command I tried, because the + - are not also reordered and then + -12y doesn't get automatically simplified to just - 12y

Comment: how is `y` a higher power than `x^5`? Needs more clarity.

Comment: @TheBatman I think OP just wants to reverse it, and it has nothing to do with any reasonable order other than that.

Comment: @BACON that's a nuance of this question. Once you remove the spaces `6x^5 -12y` and `6x^5 - 12y` safely become `6x^5-12y` anyway. Also there are parsers which could make this very easy([ncalc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ncalc/) comes to mind)

Comment: @TheBatman when you deal with equations, you group terms together which is why the y and x^5 may seem confusing

Comment: @djv a parser is being used, (MathNet) and the output is in ascending order not descending

Comment: @kizzer ok, I can see how you have grouped terms first, and it's then ordered, but maybe a different example would have made it more clear. Anyway, problem solved :)

Comment: @djv yeah problem solved, perhaps a different example would have been nicer to deal with - I did try to display the problem as clearly as possible with examples. I try to solve as much as possible without asking for any help, in future should I ask for some I'll aim for even more clarity/make up a more approachable fictional scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is hardly understandable, but i think i got it right that you need just to reverse parts of equation, or they should be sorted by the power as well?

```
string str = "4x^2 + 6x^5 -12y + 3xy";

string strCopy = str;

if (str.Length != 0 && str[0] != '-') // covers case when first member is positive, if it is not enough you can use str.TrimStart()[0]
{
    strCopy = "+" + str;
}

var reverseString = string.Join(" ", strCopy
    .Replace(" ", "") // remove all spaces because they kind of random now
    .Replace("+", " +") // add space to signs to keep them with their value
    .Replace("-", " -")
    .Split(' ')
    .Reverse()
)
.TrimStart('+') // remove plus if positive number on the right
.Replace(" +", " + ") // fix spaces back
.Replace(" -", " - ");

Console.WriteLine(strCopy);
Console.WriteLine(reverseString);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Result

[image]

Comment: I believe this will fail if the starting member is positive without a plus sign. For example, if the input is `4x^2 + 6x^5 -12y + 3xy`, the result would be `3xy - 12y + 6x^5 4x^2`

Comment: @Guilherme thanks, I've adjusted the logic, so it would append plus beforehand :)

Comment: @pwrigshihanomoronimo Thank you so much, this is just what was needed and I've just finished testing it. Apologies if you found the question difficult to understand, I did try to clearly explain it in detail and with examples.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use a Character array and then split the string first in order to achieve this. After this is done then you can use a string to get the string output.

```
string valueStr = "-4x^2 + 6x^5 -12y + 3xy";
string result = string.Join(" ", valueStr.Split(new char[] { ' ' }).Reverse());
```

Comment: This is identical to what's in the question except you're explicitly passing a `char[]` to the `params` parameter of `Split()`.